# How to add a setting to the WordPress Gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to write a simple plugin that will alter the behavior of the Edit Post screen (now called Gutenberg). I'm using `@wordpress/scripts` to bundle the javascript. The following code will work to get the control to appear... but when I click the toggle it reloads the page instead of changing the state.

What am I doing wrong? I can't find any documentation on how to use state in the context of the Gutenberg editor.

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginMoreMenuItem } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { pencil } from '@wordpress/icons';
import { ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';
 
const HemingwayModeToggleControl = withState( {
    hemingwayMode: false,
} )( ( { hemingwayMode, setState } ) => (
    <ToggleControl
        label="Hemingway mode"
        help={ hemingwayMode ? 'Hemingway mode is on.' : 'Hemingway mode is off.' }
        checked={ hemingwayMode }
        onChange={ () => setState( ( state ) => ( { hemingwayMode: ! state.hemingwayMode } ) ) }
    />
) );

const HemingwayModeMoreMenuItem = () => (
    <PluginMoreMenuItem
        icon={pencil}
    >
        <HemingwayModeToggleControl />
    </PluginMoreMenuItem>
);

registerPlugin( 'hemingway-mode-more-menu', { render: HemingwayModeMoreMenuItem } );
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that every component in this slot is wrapped with `<button></button>`. So, when you hit your toggle, you rather hit this button. But in your case I think this is not important, and you can use button onClick event to set your state. Here is updated code and it is working.

```
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginMoreMenuItem } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { pencil } from '@wordpress/icons';
import { ToggleControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { withState } from '@wordpress/compose';

const HemingwayModeMoreMenuItem = withState( {hemingwayMode: false} )(
    ({ hemingwayMode, setState }) => (
        <PluginMoreMenuItem
            icon={pencil}
            onClick={ (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setState( ( state ) => ( { hemingwayMode: ! state.hemingwayMode } ) )
            } }
        >

        <ToggleControl
            label="Hemingway mode"
            help={ hemingwayMode ? 'Hemingway mode is on.' : 'Hemingway mode is off.' }
            checked={ hemingwayMode }
        />

        </PluginMoreMenuItem>
    )
);

registerPlugin( 'hemingway-mode-more-menu', { render: HemingwayModeMoreMenuItem } );
```

The rest problem is, that More Tools & Options section closes when the button is clicked. This behaviour is default and I do not know how to override it.

Comment: Thanks! You said "More Tools & Options section closes when the button is clicked" but I don't see that behavior when I toggle the default options. Ex: code vs visual editor mode. Do you know of any way to replicate that behavior? That was my first instinct but the docs said specifically not to use that component for simply turning a setting on/off

Comment: I get an unhelpful error when I run this code: `TypeError: a is not a function`